# django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: MySQL 8 or later is required (found 5.7.33). in Django

Tags: python, django

I have this error when performing migrations to my file command

I tried this command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

**but Error insist**

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: MySQL 8 or later is required (found 5.7.33).
```

Is there anyway to perform migration? or should I downgrade my python version to v.9?

**python version**

```
python v.3.10
```

Answer (score 9):

Django versions 4.2 and onwards dropped support for MySQL 5.7, and supports only MySQL 8
See here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.2/#dropped-support-for-mysql-5-7

My suggestion to you is to stay with Django 4.1 or upgrade you MySQL server to version 8

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when you try to run a Django application that requires MySQL 8 or later, but the MySQL version installed on your system is 5.7.33 or earlier.

Django 3.2 and later versions require MySQL 8.0.25 or later because they use features that are not available in earlier versions of MySQL.

To fix this error, you need to upgrade your MySQL installation to version 8 or later. You can do this by downloading the latest version of [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) from the official website and following the installation instructions.

After upgrading MySQL, you also need to update the settings.py file of your Django project to use the new version of MySQL. You can do this by changing the 'ENGINE' setting in the DATABASES dictionary to `'django.db.backends.mysql'` and specifying the appropriate `'HOST', 'PORT', 'USER', 'PASSWORD',` and `'NAME'` settings for your MySQL database.

If you're using a database management tool like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench, you can check the version of MySQL that's installed by running the following SQL query:

```
SELECT @@version;
```

This will return the version of MySQL that's currently installed on your system.

Answer (score 2):

You can install an older version of django with
pip install Django==3.2.19 command

Comment: This appears to be a comment for an existing answer. Please only post answers in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

Install Django 4.1 with using `pip3 install django==4.1` that supports mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

You should install mysqlclient using pip: `pip uninstall mysqlclient`

You can also uninstall the old mysql engine which supports only `mysql5.7`. And install other mysql client package which supports `mysql8.0`. by using `pip install mysql-connector-python`.

And then you change the settings of the database connection as below-

`'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django'`